# How to make a "local object" in Python?

Tags: python, object, global, local

I wonder why Python behaves differently in the cases below?

**Case 1.** I change local integer variable but global variable remains the same. Well, that's OK.

```
N = 1

def Func1(x):
    x = 0

Func1(N)
print(N) # prints 1
```

**Case 2.** I change property of local object... and it seems that I've changed global object.

```
class C1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = 1

Obj1 = C1()

def Func2(x):
    x.A = 0  #here is a confusing moment

Func2(Obj1)
print(Obj1.A) #prints 0
```

Maybe I have incomplete understanding about can object actually be local or not? In that case how can I code something similar to "local object"?

Comment: You didn't change the global object. You changed the data in the global object.

Comment: How can I create something like global object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, arguments to functions are *passed by assignment*. [1]
And in python, objects are not copied on assignment.
So in your second example, to make what you call a *local copy* of the object, you will have to copy it explicitly, for instance using `copy.deepcopy(x)` [2]

So your second code would become:

```
import copy
class C1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = 1

Obj1 = C1()

def Func2(x):
    x = copy.deepcopy(x) # Make a local copy of the object
    x.A = 0  #No more confusion

Func2(Obj1)
print(Obj1.A) #prints 1
```

[1] https://docs.python.org/3.4/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference

[2] https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

Answer (score 0):

Your comparing apples to oranges(or whatever you wanna say). In your first case you were trying to change the value of a global variable inside of a function. Your global variable did not change when you called a function because **Python passes variables by assignment not by reference**. Observe what happens when we pass by assignment in your first case:

```
>>> N = 1
>>> def foo(x):
    x = 0
    return x

>>> foo(N) # this will not change N. we need to pass N by assingment
0
>>> N
1
>>> N = foo(N) # this will change N
>>> N
0
>>>
```

This behavior is documented in [Python3 FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference):

> Remember that **arguments are passed by assignment in Python**. Since assignment just creates references to objects, there’s no alias between an argument name in the caller and callee, and so no call-by-reference per se.

The emphasis is mine.

In your second case, you did not change the value of a global variable. `Obj1` is an object not a variable. **You changed the attribute of `Obj1` not `Obj1` itself**. See what happens when we attempt to pass `Obj1` by reference:

```
>>> class CL:
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = 1


>>> Obj1 = CL()
>>> def foo(x):
    # lets try chaning the actual value that Obj1 holds
    x = None


>>> foo(Obj1) # did it change?
>>> Obj1
<__main__.CL object at 0x03B29B50>
>>>  # Nope
```